# Bundler, Ruby Gem, Travis-CI

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, travis-ci

I am getting the following error on Travis and I don't understand why. I have tried Googling but haven't had any luck. I assume that there is a problem with a requires line somewhere but don't know what it is. My run can be seen [here](https://travis-ci.org/genebean/puppet-moddeps/jobs/44996664) and the associated code is [on GitHub here](https://github.com/genebean/puppet-moddeps/tree/develop). I assume that the error is a result of the lines at the top of `lib/puppet/moddeps.rb` but don't know for sure. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:2
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/gems/bundler-1.7.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:1
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/ruby -I/home/travis/build/genebean/puppet-moddeps/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/lib:/home/travis/build/genebean/puppet-moddeps/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-support-3.1.2/lib /home/travis/build/genebean/puppet-moddeps/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.1.7/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb --color --format documentation failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a result of using `exec()` in my code.